# Dynamic Flexible constraint satisfaction problems

Tags: logic, clpfd, constraint-programming

I am looking for a logic constraint solver with the capability to solve flexible and/or dynamic constraints. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you define flexible/dynamic constraints? Give an example.

Comment: By dynamic I mean if the constraints in the problem keep changing over time and by flexible I mean if the constraints are not Hard - some of the constraint can be left unsatisfied of course with a cost; some of the constraints are more important. They carry a weight or rank or there is a cost function where the solver tries to keep in minimum for solving the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [OptaPlanner](http://www.optaplanner.org/) (Java, open source, ASL):

- *Dynamic* (as in keeps changing over time): The OptaPlanner constraints are maintenance friendly, because they are object orientated and isolated from each other. Also, if you use the drools integration, you can even define your constraints in a decision table, the guvnor web application, ...
- *Flexible* (as in not all constraints are hard): OptaPlanner supports [hard and soft constraints](http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/latest/optaplanner-docs/html_single/index.html#d0e3489) out-of-the-box. It supports score weighting and 3+ score levels (for example hard, medium and soft), if needed.

There's also several other constraint satisfaction libraries out there.

Comment: Thanks a lot Geoffrey, you comment was very helpful. I will check it out.

Comment: Dear Geoffrey, I could not find the functions I can use for solving Flexible (soft) constraints. I would appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

"By dynamic I mean if the constraints in the problem keep changing over time" --> this does not make sense in Constraint Programming. Constraints does not change. Only the domains of variables can change (by constraint propagation or decisions).

"by flexible I mean if the constraints are not Hard - some of the constraint can be left unsatisfied of course with a cost; some of the constraints are more important. They carry a weight or rank or there is a cost function where the solver tries to keep in minimum for solving the problem." --> Ok So basically you are trying to solve Max-CSPs and/or Weighted-CSPs. I propose that you check one of the CSP-competitions that support max and/or weighted CSP (for instance http://www.cril.univ-artois.fr/CPAI08/). You can also check Minizinc for that http://www.minizinc.org (but I'm not sure if it supports max/weighted CSPs).

What kind of problems are you trying to solve?

Comment: thanks for your answer, I will check them out. About the dynamic constraints, I meant that the set of constraints keeps changing over time; new constraints are added or some of the old constraints are removed. For instance when you are solving an investigation problem, you get new information about the crime scene over time